# Why is the angular momentum written as JJ in quantum mechanics?

Tags: reference-request, quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

Why is $\textbf{J}$ called angular momentum operator? Can anyone explain why the expectation value of J is angular momentum?

Here is how $J$ is defined: The rotation operator
$$
U(\alpha)=\exp(-i {\bf \alpha} \cdot \mathbf{J})
$$
Rotates the system around the direction of $\alpha$, through an angle $|\alpha |$.

Sorry that this is not quite research level, but I cannot find some intuitive explanation about this elsewhere.

Comment: This question would be more suitable for [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions), and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator#Angular_momentum_as_the_generator_of_rotations) already has an answer:"*The most general and fundamental definition of angular momentum is as the generator of rotations*". It is essentially the same in classical mechanics, just the generation is described in more elementary terms with cross product or quaternions.

Comment: As pointed out you should ask the question in physics SE, but it is because you can check that it obeys $[J_k, J_p]=\varepsilon_{kpi} J_i$. This property is also obeyed by the "orbital" angular momentum defined by $\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{\hat{x}}\times\mathbf{\hat{p}}$ in analogy with classical mechanics, and it turns out that commutation relation, loosely speaking, is the most general way to define something that behaves like an angular momentum