# Why is 'total angular momentum' denoted by the letter $J$ in quantum mechanics?

Tags: terminology, notation, quantum-mechanics

In quantum mechanics, we say $J$ ('total angular momentum') = $L$ ('orbital angular momentum') + $S$ ('spin angular momentum').

Apparently $S$ is from 'Spin', but why $J$ for the total angular momentum?

cf) [Why is the angular momentum written as JJ in quantum mechanics?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6993/why-is-the-angular-momentum-written-as-jj-in-quantum-mechanics) : this question does not seem to answer the history of the notation

Comment: You will probably have to start from the references here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/728/why-did-angular-momentum-get-the-letter-l?rq=1